# Linking Amazon pinpoint endpoint email and GCM/FCM token

Tags: android, email, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, aws-pinpoint

The problem I am facing is that I am able to segment users and send them Push notifications, but if I want to send emails to the same set of users, I am unable to do that.

Is there a way I can link emails with GCM/FCM Token in Amazon Pinpoint?

So that I have to segment my users just once, and I can send them both push notifications and emails.

Answer (score 1):

Each different way you can engage a customer is represented as its own Endpoint in Amazon Pinpoint.  This means that ***each*** device, email, or phone number should be its own Endpoint.

Endpoints can not only include custom `Endpoint Attributes` but also custom `User Attributes`.  Just like `Endpoint Attributes`s, `User Attributes`s get merged into existing attributes. They will also update user attributes **across** endpoints with matching `UserId`. [1]

This allows you to target multiple endpoints per user when segmenting on custom User Attributes using the `UserAttributes` segmentation field. [2]

Creating a cross-channel Campaign (email + FCM/GCM) is currently not supported in the console, but can be achieved by creating a campaign whose segment includes all the ChannelTypes you'd like to target (`EMAIL`, `GCM`). [3]

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-endpoints.html#rest-api-endpoints-attributes-endpointuser-table

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-segment.html#rest-api-segment-attributes-writesegmentrequest-table

[3] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-segment.html